# Is it possible to stretch an image in pygames?

Tags: python, pygame

Is it possible to stretch an image in pygame using an event to trigger it?

Like say I have a person and I want his eyes to popout like this
[image]
  when I press a button and I am using `surface.blit(eyes=pygame.image.load('eyes'))` for the eyes.

Can i stretch the eye image like the picture in this link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution to this problem that allows you to stretch the eyes to the exact width you want, but it may make the eyes very deformed... (nevermind, the original image has pretty deformed eyes anyway.)

From the Pygame doc on [pygame.transform.scale](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale):

> scale(Surface, (width, height), DestSurface = None) -> Surface

We also use image.[get_height](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_height)() so the user does not have to get the height themselves.

So you would do something like this (wrapped in a function):

```
def stretchEyes(image, newWidth):
    return pygame.transform.scale(image, (image.get_height(), newWidth))

eyes = stretchEyes(eyes, image.get_width()*3) # Stretch to three times width
# Blitting takes in the top left position, so we don't need to do any maths here!
screen.blit(eyes, (x,y))
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to have two images one for the actual image and one where the eyes are stretched. Draw the second image whenever you need instead of the first image.

[image: runner1.jpg]

[image: runner2.jpg]

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((540, 480))
runner1 = pygame.image.load('./runner1.jpg').convert()
runner1_rect = runner1.get_rect(center=(270, 240))
runner2 = pygame.image.load('./runner2.jpg').convert()
runner2_rect = runner2.get_rect(center=(270, 240))
screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
change = True
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            screen.blit(runner2, runner2_rect)
            pygame.display.update()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            screen.blit(runner1, runner1_rect)
            pygame.display.update()
```

As shown in the above example, we get images(sprites) of different postures and play them as and when we need to get the motion.

To begin and understand the pygame start from [PUMMEL THE CHIMP](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/chimp/ChimpLineByLine.html) and there are good API to handle sprites and their behavior through pygame.